# SQL Server : converting multiple rows into single row from inner joining tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble with some query since I have multiple rows for the same timestamp.

```
| 1 | 2017-09-21 08:52:18.000 | 120 | 255 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |          |
| 2 | 2017-09-21 08:52:18.000 |     |     |   |   |   |   | 17203200 |
```

I want the result to be

```
| R | 2017-09-21 08:52:18.000 | 120 | 255 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 17203200 |
```

Because it's the same data but since they are from different tables it creates 2 or more rows, I want to squish this to one Row with all of the values and if both have values I want to keep the highest value.

Comment: What's your rationale of choosing the first row instead of the second?  What's the table structure, column name, ... Here's a good info about how to ask question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It looks like your wanting to act like string concatenation.

STUFF might be a good method to use, but you need to utilize the unique need for your last column, do you have a need to show the greatest value in that last column, or just the fact that the first row column is empty?

Comment: Define: "i want to keep the Highest value."  max group by seems like it would work  bug if col 3 2nd record had 130 and col4 2nd record had 200 you'd be mixing/matching values.  Are you sure this is what you want?  or is it that would never happen because only the timestamp is filled in on "both" records"

Comment: Please add information about the table structure and the specific SQL query you executed.

Answer (score 3):

You can try it

```
Declare @Table table (
 Column1 int    
,Column2 datetime 
,Column3 int 
,Column4 int 
,Column5 int 
,Column6 int 
,Column7 int 
,Column8 int 
,Column9 int 
,Column10 int
)


INSERT @Table Values
(1,'2017-09-21 08:52:18.000',120,255,0,0,0,0, NULL,NULL                        )
,(2,'2017-09-21 08:52:18.000',NULL ,NULL , NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,17203200,NULL)


SELECT
Column2 
,Max(Isnull(Column3 ,0)) Column3
,Max(Isnull(Column4 ,0)) Column4
,Max(Isnull(Column5 ,0)) Column5
,Max(Isnull(Column6 ,0)) Column6
,Max(Isnull(Column7 ,0)) Column7
,Max(Isnull(Column8 ,0)) Column8
,Max(Isnull(Column9 ,0)) Column9
,Max(Isnull(Column10,0)) Column10

FROM 
    @Table
Group By 
Column2
```